# Create a web-based chat box using AJAX, PHP, and SQL Long Polling?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, chat, long-polling

I'm creating an online chat box for me and my friends at college to use online. In the current configuration, the chat messages are stored in a plain text file on the host machine (mine) and are fetched via AJAX every second, however, sometimes it is slow and glitchy and doesn't always work.

To send a message, it passes the message to a JavaScript function which passes the value to a PHP script, writing it to the file along with the user's unique color (stored in a local cookie). Here's the functions.js file (pastebin): http://pastebin.com/CpGxj5cP

Here's the php file to send the message:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('mysql_connect.php');
date_default_timezone_set("EST");

//Format the message
$date = date('n/j g:i A');
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$color = $_COOKIE[$username];

$message  = "<font color='" . $color . "'>" . $username . "</font> (" .  $date . "): ";
$message .= $_GET['m'] . "\n";

$file = '../messages.txt';

$handle = fopen($file, 'a');
fputs($handle, $message);

fclose($handle);

//Reset timeout
//$_SESSION['timeout'] = 300;
?>
```

As I said above, the issue is that it's very very slow. If there's a way to do it better than a textfile/AJAX, please let me know!

Comment: its the deprecated html **font** that makes it slow

Comment: would using `<style>` make it better?

Comment: css would definitely improve the speed.

Comment: That' didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a better way if you are using a browser that supports HTML 5

Web Sockets

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_websocket.htm

Comment: How would I go about implementing WebSockets into a web-based chat application that pulls the messages from a PHP script?

Comment: here is a good tutorial on how to do this with PHP and websockets
http://blog.ilric.org/2011/02/14/super-simple-chat-using-websockets/

Answer (score 0):

Check this out for a full code of a chat box using PHP. Download the source code or see the live demo in this site.

*Moderator note: This link is no longer alive, and archive.org does not seem to have a copy, either.*
`http://purpledesign.in/blog/?p=19`

```
    function getLoginBox() {
    ob_start();
    require_once('login_form.html');
    $sLoginForm = ob_get_clean();

    $sLogoutForm = '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?logout=1">logout</a>';

    if ((int)$_REQUEST['logout'] == 1) {
        if (isset($_COOKIE['member_name']) && isset($_COOKIE['member_pass']))
            $this->simple_logout();
    }

    if ($_REQUEST['username'] && $_REQUEST['password']) {
        if ($this->check_login($_REQUEST['username'], MD5($_REQUEST['password']))) {
            $this->simple_login($_REQUEST['username'], $_REQUEST['password']);
            return 'Hello ' . $_REQUEST['username'] . '! ' . $sLogoutForm;
        } else {
            return 'Username or Password is incorrect' . $sLoginForm;
        }
    } else {
        if ($_COOKIE['member_name'] && $_COOKIE['member_pass']) {
            if ($this->check_login($_COOKIE['member_name'], $_COOKIE['member_pass'])) {
                return 'Hello ' . $_COOKIE['member_name'] . '! ' . $sLogoutForm;
            }
        }
        return $sLoginForm;
    }
}
```

Of course you will need to create a log in box. Kindly check the link I have shared. It has all the details

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.