# PHP MySQL and ajax practice projects

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

What are some good simple projects for practicing PHP and mysql work?? Also implementing Ajax??
I am fairly new to PHP and mysql, and would like to gain more experience, I also enjoy using Ajax and xml

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) framework?

Comment: I haven't had a good look at it yet, i enjoy learning the roots before going into the frameworks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most simple one is a Signup/Login Form.

1. While, signing up use JS to validate the form, and ajax call to submit the form data. And while taking a userId as input, you can use ajax call "onchange" to verify it's existence.
2. Then go for an Quiz App.
3. Self issuing Online Library.
4. And, the best one Online Pizza Ordering System.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying to implement things that Facebook does, for example-

1. [Tagging a person as you type their name](https://www.9lessons.info/2010/08/tag-friends-with-jquery-ajax-and-php.html)
2. [A simple chat box.](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-simple-web-based-chat-application--net-5931) Also take a look at this [SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18860054/create-a-web-based-chat-box-using-ajax-php-and-sql-long-polling)

Some more googling gives you [25 Excellent Ajax Techniques and Examples](https://www.webpagefx.com/blog/web-design/ajax_techniques/)